# Can this puzzle be solved using the representation theory of quivers?

Tags: representation-theory, puzzle, quiver

This riddle originates in the youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sBB-gRhfjE). It's mathematical content was summarised [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/8olne3/graphs_with_edge_functions_instead_of_edge_costs/?st=ji1i0o7w&sh=8b571817) as follows:

> There's a $5\times 5$ grid of nodes, all nodes are (bidirectionally) connected to their vertical and horizontal neighbour(s) (so no diagonals). the nodes have coordinates $(x,y)$, with $x=0\dots 4$, $y=0\dots 4$
>
> - you start at node $(2,4)$ and already have a "cost" of $4$.
> - moving down a node (so $y$ decreased by $1$) doubles that cost,
> - moving up a node (so $y$ increased by $1$) halves the cost,
> - moving left (so $x$ decreased by $1$) decreases the cost by two,
> - moving right (so $x$ increased by $1$) increases the cost by $2$.
> - an edge can only occur once in your path, you may pass nodes multiple times though.
>
> is there a way to get to the lower right corner, point $(4,0)$, with a cost equal to zero?

The questioner in my second link wanted to know if there was a nice way to represent the problem mathematically. I suggested we could use quivers.

The graph in the problem can be thought of as a quiver where each vertex is connected both ways with each adjacent vertex. Since the cost functions are all affine, they can be represented as a representation of a quiver:

- Each vertex is represented by $\mathbb R^2$.
- The downward edges are represented by the matrix \begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
- the upward edges by the matrix \begin{pmatrix}1/2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
- the leftward edges by the matrix \begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
- and the rightward edges by the matrix \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
- Then the matrices represent the changes in cost by acting on \begin{pmatrix}\text{cost}\\1\end{pmatrix}

Now I'm wondering if we can use the representation theory of quivers to solve the puzzle?

---

I'm not an expert in quivers, but I did notice that the vectors of the form \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} span a subrepresentation. Are representations of quivers always completely reducible? If so then finding the complementary representation might help.

Comment: Representations of quivers are "almost never" completely reducible.